# Email Reply to multiple email addresses

Tags: php

I want to send email reply to multiple email addresses. Actually there are more then one admins and i want that all of these should receive email reply.
Right now i am using this

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". admin@example.com . "\r\n";
```

It is working fine for one email address but i do not know how i can implement this for multiple email addresses.
Actually i have an array of email addresses that are separated with commas and i want that all of these should receive email reply.
How i can implement this ?
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it acceptable to send the email to a system account, and then cc each of the other email addresses?

Comment: No. Actually i want to implement this directly with "reply-to". I am not sure it is possible or not.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2) says:

> In either case, an optional reply-to field MAY also be included, which
> contains the field name "Reply-To" and a comma-separated list of one
> or more addresses.

So, all you need to do is implode that array of yours into a comma-separated list.

```
$emails = array ( "john@doe.com", "jane@doe.com", "will@doe.com");
$str = implode (",", $emails); //john@doe.com,jane@doe.com,will@doe.com
$headers .= "Reply-To: $str\r\n"
```

Comment: Gotta love an answer with a link to the RFC.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done it with reply-to, but if it works the same as CC, then doing it like this should be possible.

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: 1st@address.com,2nd@address.com\r\n"
```